# Improve query performance in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-performance

I have a table with 150 million rows with a non-clustered index on `userId`. I have to write a query to filter on `userId` and return all the rows if the `productType` is not **SIG** and return only rows greater than the last 90 days if the `productType` is **SIG**. All the columns from the table shoule be returned (unfortunately).

I created a similar table with about 10 million rows. Took me about 10 min to create it.

**Execution plan:**
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJM-XOq0j

The optimizer does an index seek on the `userId` and then does a key lookup to get the rest of the columns and also applying additional criteria. Is there a better way to do this?

```
set nocount on

Declare @userId UniqueIdentifier, @i Int = 0, @j Int = 1, @k Int = 1, @productType Varchar(100)
Declare @date datetime, @userId1 varchar(100)
Declare @type1 varchar(100),
@type2 varchar(100),
@type3 varchar(100),
@type4 varchar(100),
@type5 varchar(100),
@type6 varchar(100),
@type7 varchar(100),
@type8 varchar(100),
@type9 varchar(100),
@type10 varchar(100),
@type11 varchar(100),
@type12 varchar(100)

Create Table #tmpProducts
(
productId Int primary key Identity(1,1),
userId UniqueIdentifier,
productType varchar(100),
createdDate Datetime,
type1 varchar(100),
type2 varchar(100),
type3 varchar(100),
type4 varchar(100),
type5 varchar(100),
type6 varchar(100),
type7 varchar(100),
type8 varchar(100),
type9 varchar(100),
type10 varchar(100),
type11 varchar(100),
type12 varchar(100)
)

While @i<=100
begin

  --declare @msg varchar(100) = 'step' + convert(varchar(10),@i)
  -- RAISERROR (@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    set @userId = newId()
    set @userId1 = convert(varchar(100), @userId)
    set @j = 1
    set @k = 1
    while @j <= 5
    begin
        Set @productType = Case When @j = 1 Then 'SIG' 
                            When @j = 2 Then 'FIG'
                            When @j = 3 Then 'MKT'
                            When @j = 4 Then 'LPP'
                            When @j = 5 Then 'POC'
                           End

          while @k < 100000
          begin
            print @k
            set @date = case when @k < 1000 Then  DateAdd(day,-180,getdate())
                             When @k > 1000 and @k < 99500 Then DateAdd(day,-91,getdate())
                             else getdate()
                          end
            set @type1 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '1'
            set @type2 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '2'
            set @type3 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '3'
            set @type4 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '4'
            set @type5 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '5'
            set @type6 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '6'
            set @type7 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '7'
            set @type8 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '8'
            set @type9 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '9'
            set @type10 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '10'
            set @type11 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '11'
            set @type12 = @userId1 + convert(varchar(10),@k) + '12'

           Insert Into #tmpProducts values (@userId, @productType, @date,@type1, @type2,@type3,@type4,@type5,@type6,@type7,@type8,@type9,@type10,@type11,@type12)
           set @k = @k + 1
          end
        set @j = @j + 1
    end

    set @i = @i + 1
End

Create nonclustered index idx_ptype on #tmpProducts(userId)

Select * 
  from #tmpProducts
 Where userId = '78EAC797-4399-4D4A-A8E3-54F2732EE0E0' --replace the memberId with the id from your dataset
   And (productType != 'SIG'
     or (productType = 'SIG'
           and createdDate >= Convert(date, dateadd(day,-90,getdate()))
        )
        )

--drop table if exists #tmpProducts
```

Comment: This sounds like a good job for the [index change you asked about](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/324076/32281). Did that not get what you'd hoped for?

Comment: The table has 150 million rows - what is the maximum number of rows that any one `userId` has? And also for this "per user" number how many rows will meet the `=SIG` condition and how many not? And of the rows meeting the `=SIG` condition how many meet the " last 90 day" condition?

Comment: Even with the index change, i'm still getting a key lookup. Do I need to live with it? Can I use a CTE to use the narrow index and then join it back to the table on the clustered index to get all the other columns?

Comment: " use a CTE to use the narrow index and then join it back to the table on the clustered index to get all the other columns" - you are just doing exactly what the key lookup is doing then.

Comment: @MartinSmith The maximum number of rows a user has is 20k currently. SIG for the user that has 20k rows is 5k and of those 5k rows, 1k is in the last 90 days. The average number of rows per user is around 1k rows and the average SIG rows are 500 and average SIG rows in the last 90 days are 100.

Comment: So in the worst case the query returns 16k rows from the 20K lookups and in the general case it returns 600 rows and does 1k lookups?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the speed if you had an index of (UserID,ProductType). That would at least speed up looking for the SIG. If that works, try adding the createdDate to the index.

Comment: The index `(userId, productType, createdDate) INCLUDE (type1,  type2,  type3,  type4,  type5,  type6,  type7,  type8,  type9,  type10,  type11,  type12)` works fine without a key lookup https://dbfiddle.uk/wO8VV8Iy

Comment: That would be a very large index especially with type_* columns are all varchars.